# TFlite Select Ops in C++ inference without using FlexDelegate

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to build a TFLite program to run inference with a model which uses TF Select Ops written in C++ without building the entire tflite delegate library, i.e. without adding flex delegate as a dependency in the BUILD file (using bazel here). Keeping the flex delegate in allows the program to build and run on x86_64, but cross-compilation for RaspberryPI fails, and furthermore, the binary is nearly an order of magnitude larger than expected. Is it possible to use ops which are not natively supported by TFLite in a TFlite C++ program without building the entire delegate library?

Answer (score 0):

I think selective build is what you are looking for: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/reduce_binary_size
It only links the ops that are used in your models so vastly reduce the library size.
Follow the instruction on that page, you can produce .aar files, extracting that file you will find the .so libraries.

Comment: So build an AAR as if I'm building for android, and then I can extract and use the .so file on a non-android ARM device?

Comment: Specifically, looking to build for `elinux_armhf`

Comment: The .so there is only suitable for JNI usage. For other usage you can consider defining a tflite_flex_cc_library which is defining here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/delegates/flex/build_def.bzl

Comment: How would we go about doing that? Could you provide more specific details? Does this require BUILD file modifications?

Comment: Right. You need to modify the build file and rebuild. An example is in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/delegates/flex/test/BUILD